# pytest xdist and setup hook execution

Tags: pytest, xdist, pytest-xdist

I am having trouble getting my plugin `pytest_runtest_setup` hook executing with xdist plugin. It executes without specifying -n option, but as soon as I specify that option the hook doesn't execute.

My `pytest_runtest_makereport` always works. Any ideas?

Comment: Tell us the versions of pytest and pytest-xdist, show us the code of your hook. I have few per-package conftest files with `pytest_runtest_setup` hooks and tests work as they should, with or without xdist

Comment: I have obseved the same issue with pytest version 2.9.2 and xdsit version 1.4.2. Any suggestion please. In may case `pytest_runtest_makereport` also doesn't work with xdist.